# Cannot get DKIM working with Exim4

Tags: ubuntu, email, exim, ubuntu-16.04, dkim

I've tried everything I can think of to get DKIM working with Exim4 on my Ubuntu 16.04 server, but emails sent from my server are still not signed with DKIM!

I am using Exim4, unsplit configuration.

I generated private and public keys using these commands in /etc/exim4/dkim:

```
sudo openssl genrsa -out dkim.key 1024
sudo openssl rsa -in dkim.key -pubout > dkim.pub
```

I edited the following lines in /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template:

```
.ifdef DKIM_DOMAIN
dkim_domain = ${lc:${domain:$h_from}}
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_SELECTOR
dkim_selector = mail
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY
dkim_private_key = /etc/exim4/dkim/dkim.key
.endif
.ifdef DKIM_CANON
dkim_canon = relaxed
.endif
```

Then ran these commands:

```
sudo update-exim4.conf
sudo service exim4 restart
```

Added this TXT record to my DNS records (using the public key):

```
TXT mail._domainkey "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCvnoSm2o5X9JoCKfYlhkRv5mj4yRscjlv5JmNj1PfBeZGp57XgriRCcA4S5/egrPI2VfKzoCwRsGp4uCD/UJ7+6DgCVNseSlD+n6n4mRANWWlfY7LvHfp8sAR80aurwNyx7/PHGg+ZukHcllvYCtZtg4jtZTrl8w1yiKXyJ3G3fQIDAQAB"
```

Sent an email from my server to my Gmail address, and it went straight to spam. I click "Show original" and DKIM is not mentioned anywhere in the email headers.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `DKIM_*` variables defined to trigger `ifdef`s? Do you have multiple sending domains or single one that can be defined explicitly?

Comment: @Kondybas Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "```DKIM_*``` variables defined to trigger ```ifdef```s". Could you explain to me how this works? I have multiple websites (sending domains) on this server, but I also have two more servers with just one sending domain each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exim`allows conditional runtime configuration.

```
XXXX = something

.ifdef XXXX
<some directives>
.endif
```

If variable XXXX have some value assigned then it becomes "defined" and `.ifdef XXXX` is evaluated to `TRUE`. Even if XXXX is defined as `XXXX = false` it is still defined somehow. Line should be commented out to prevent definition. Bundled config contains lot of config snippents for many situations but they are usually disabled by control variables commented out.

In your case you have to find where the `DKIM_DOMAIN`, `DKIM_SELECTOR`, `DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY` and the rest of `DKIM_*` variables defined and uncomment them.

Comment: I could kiss you!!! I changed /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template back to the default, created /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros and defined the four variables in there. Then ran ```sudo update-exim4.conf``` and ```sudo service exim4 restart```. It's finally working, thanks so much!!